# Faster cpu wastes more time as compared to slower cpu

Tags: performance, cpu, clock, cpu-architecture

Suppose I have a program that has an instruction to add two numbers and that operation takes 10 nanoseconds(constant, as enforced by the gate manufactures).
 
Now I have 3 different processors A, B and C(where A< B < C  in terms of clock cycles). 
A's one clock cycle has 15 nanosec, B has 10 nanosec and C has 7 nanosec.
Firstly am I correct on my following assumptions- 
1. Add operation takes 1 complete cycle of processor A(slow processor) and wastes rest of 5 ns of the cycle.
2. Add operation takes 1 complete cycle of processor B wasting no time.
3. Add operation takes 2 complete cycles(20 ns) of processor C(fast processor) wasting rest of the 20-14=7 ns.

If the above assumptions are correct then isn't this a contradiction to the regular assumption that processors with high clock cycles are faster.
 Here processor C which is the fastest actually takes 2 cycles and wastes 7ns whereas, the slower processor A takes just 1 cycle.

Comment: This is like asking "what if I have a faster car, but the road forces cars to take 1 hour to drive along it - are faster cars wasting more speed?". It doesn't make sense. The clock is what tells the parts of a CPU to work, it's the drumbeat which keeps one part of the chip from getting ahead of another part. Things change when the clock tells them to. If you just say "CPU C has a faster clock, but adding takes 10nS", how is it a faster CPU? What's the faster clock doing? You've disconnected the clock from its job. Adding might take a fixed *ten cycles* but not a fixed *10nS*.

Comment: I mentioned that cpu C is faster and therefore has high clock rate which means lower time per cycle which here is 7ns. Now said that, addition takes constant 10ns so it won't get completed in one cpu C cycle and would need 2 of it therefore.

Comment: or is my initial assumption wrong that addition takes constant time because a faster CPU would do addition in less time, here less than 10ns

Comment: Your math is wrong btw, 2 cycles at 7ns per cycle is 14 ns, wasting 4.

Comment: @harold glad to see you here. yea I went bit wrong. So here isn't the faster  cpu lagging behind.

Comment: And I said that doesn't make sense. If addition takes 10nS on processor A and B and C, why do you say C is faster? If it takes the same time to do addition, it's not faster. Instructions are tied to clock cycles, not time. That's how a faster clock makes for a faster processor - by doing more instructions per second. In your world where addition magically takes a fixed time and the clock does nothing, who knows what will happen. e.g. processor A addition "takes 10nS" and also "takes 1 complete 15nS cycle" and also "wastes 5nS". It's only "waste" because the clock isn't doing anything.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler it does make sense though, it's tied to the clock only up to the point where a cycle is not long enough anymore for the circuit to settle, it's a bit mad to push past that but if you must do it you can. Not with any *given* processor, but if you were designing it to meet a particular frequency instead of a performance target, because maybe you're fighting in the MHz Wars, you totally could.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler 
 
I have two very basic questions to which I'm still confused. 1.What does a ADD instruction mean, does it purely mean only and only ADD(with operands available at the registers) or does it mean getting the operands, decoding the instruction and then actually adding the numbers. 2. Based on the above context to what add actually means, how many cycles does add take, one or more than one. Everyone has a different opinion on these two questions which confuses me so much. Kindly reply.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler push past the clock period which is just short enough for an adder of your word size to do its business. You can use a higher speed so that the addition doesn't fit in a cycle any more. Then you get OP's machine C, where an addition takes multiple cycles.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes but you're looking at it from the wrong angle, I talked with OP in chat earlier so I know what he's up to - he's saying you have some adder in hardware and you design the processor around it, with a certain design frequency. There is no spec sheet - you're writing it.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler why is clock cycle a standard since it can vary with processor to processor. Shouldn't nanosec be the standard. Atleast its fixed.

Comment: Yes @harold is correct.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 instructions tied to clock cycles is 'standard' because "processing" is made of electric voltages which change when the clock triggers them to change. Adding numbers in two registers takes a known amount of voltage changes to do (how many depends on the CPU design), so it takes an amount of clock cycles. You can run the clock faster and add faster. It doesn't make sense to say how many nS it will take because it varies with clock speed. If you are designing a CPU with fixed instructions-per-nS (why??) then ... why would you also vary the clock speed in CPU A, B, C?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler you're forgetting about static logic I think, certainly that adder should be combinational logic, not sequential.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3: Please read the immediate above comment by TessellatingHeckler in contrast with my answer. You will get the complete idea.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes ok, but the clock will still be tied to instructions - in A the add instruction will have a latency of 15, in C 14 (in B, well, 1 cycle addition is not realistic because of overhead, but it was intended as the addition *just* fitting in a cycle). Because the work is completed some time before the next instruction can run, OP says that time is "wasted" (Paul A. Clayton mentions a few possible uses for it). It's about the mismatch between the speed of the sequential logic and the delay of the combinational logic in between.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the time is wasted (in the sense that nothing is happening, just waiting) if the work is done but the next instruction still has to wait for the next cycle to come along. (or not wasted, but using it takes Paul's tricks, it isn't something happens naturally; this especially makes it a bit vague I suppose)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler """ You can run the clock faster and add faster.""" this means that basically the clock forces operations to be done. Clock is basically a deadline during which the operation scheduled has to be done no matter what happens. If one clock cycle is 10ns then operation will be done in 10ns, if it is overclocked to 1ns then operation will be done in 1ns. The clock FORCES THE CPU to do stuff which is scheduled to be done in one cycle, in one cycle. Am I correct this way ?

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 probably real processors are much more complicated than I know, but yes - that is what I'm saying. The clock is in control, the clock IS the speed things happen at. A higher clock speed makes a processor 'faster' *because* it forces every operation to happen faster, so it does more operations and more work every second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processor C is fastest, no matter what. It takes 7 ns per cycle and therefore performs more cycles than A and B. It's not C's fault that the circuit is not fast enough. If you would implement the addition circuit in a way that it gives result in 1 ns, all processors will give the answer in 1 clock cycle (i.e. C will give you the answer in 7ns, B in 10ns and A in 15ns).

---

> Firstly am I correct on my following assumptions- 
>   1. Add operation takes 1 complete cycle of processor A(slow processor) and wastes rest of 5 ns of the cycle.
>   2. Add operation takes 1 complete cycle of processor B wasting no time.
>   3. Add operation takes 2 complete cycles(20 ns) of processor C(fast processor) wasting rest of the 20-7=13 ns.

No. It is because you are using incomplete data to express the time for an operation. Measure the time taken to finish an operation on a particular processor in *clock cycles* instead of *nanoseconds* as you are doing here. When you say **ADD** op takes 10 ns and you do not mention the processor on which you measured the time for the **ADD** op, the time measurement in ns is meaningless.

So when you say that **ADD** op takes 2 clock cycles on all three processors, then you have standardized the measurement. A standardized measurement can then be translated as:

- Time taken by A for addition = 2 clock cycles * 15 ns per cycle = 30 ns
- Time taken by B for addition = 2 clock cycles * 10 ns per cycle = 20 ns
- Time taken by C for addition = 2 clock cycles * 07 ns per cycle = 14 ns

---

In case you haven't noticed, when you say:

> A's one clock cycle has 15 nanosec, B has 10 nanosec and C has 7 nanosec.

which of the three processors is fastest?

Answer: C is fastest. It's one cycle is finished in 7ns. It implies that it finishes 10<sup>9</sup>/7 (~= 1.4 * 10<sup>8</sup>) cycles in one second, compared to B which finishes 10<sup>9</sup>/10 (= 10<sup>8</sup>) cycles in one second, compared to A which finishes only 10<sup>9</sup>/15 (~= 0.6 * 10<sup>8</sup>) cycles in one second.

---

> 1. What does a ADD instruction mean, does it purely mean only and only ADD(with operands available at the registers) or does it mean getting
>      the operands, decoding the instruction and then actually adding the
>      numbers.

Getting the operands is done by **MOV** op. If you are trying to compare how fast **ADD** op is being done, it should be compared by time to perform **ADD** op only. If you, on the other hand want to find out how fast addition of two numbers is being done, then it will involve more operations than simple **ADD**. However, if it's helpful, the list of all [Original 8086/8088 instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086.2F8088_instructions) is available on Wikipedia too.

> 2. Based on the above context to what add actually means, how many cycles does add take, one or more than one.

It will depend on the processor because each processor may have the adder differently implemented. There are many ways to generate addition of two numbers. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder) again - *A full adder can be implemented in many different ways such as with a custom transistor-level circuit or composed of other gates.*

Also, there may be pipelining in the instructions which can result in parallelizing of the addition of the numbers resulting in huge time savings.

> 3. Why is clock cycle a standard since it can vary with processor to processor. Shouldn't nanosec be the standard. Atleast its fixed.

Clock cycle along with the processor speed can be the standard if you want to tell the time taken by a processor to execute an instruction. Pick any two from:

- `Time to execute an instruction`,
- `Processor Speed`, and
- `Clock cycles needed for an instruction`.

The third can be derived from it.

When you say the clock cycles taken by **ADD** is *x* and you know the processor speed is *y* MHz, you can calculate that the time to **ADD** is *x / y*. Also, you can mention the time to perform **ADD** as *z* ns and you know the processor speed is same *y* MHz as earlier, you can calculate the cycles needed to execute **ADD** as *y * z*.

Comment: I think you've missed the point. OP meant that the addition circuit necessarily takes at least 10ns, due to timing constraints. There's no point in making it take two cycles in processors A and B as well, the addition fits in the clock period.

Comment: This means that no matter what type of processor is, ADD op will always take two clock cycles. No matter how fast or slow a cpu is, is this correct ?

Comment: @harold: Addition circuit does not take _time_. It takes _clock cycles_. This is what I'm saying in the line - _"...you are using wrong terminology to express the time for an operation"_.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3: Yes. Fast or slow is independent of clock cycle for an operation.

Comment: Please answer this- 
I have two very basic questions to which I'm still confused. 1.What does a ADD instruction mean, does it purely mean only and only ADD(with operands available at the registers) or does it mean getting the operands, decoding the instruction and then actually adding the numbers. 2. Based on the above context to what add actually means, how many cycles does add take, one or more than one. Everyone has a different opinion on these two questions which confuses me so much

Comment: @displayName addition circuits take time, based on the transistor size, voltage, the shape of the circuit.. that's what OP meant, you get that adder and you're building a processor around it. If you want to design it for a high enough clock speed, eventually you'll need more than 1 cycle for the adder to complete.

Comment: @displayName why is clock cycle a standard since it can vary with processor to processor. Shouldn't nanosec be the standard. Atleast its fixed

Comment: @harold: I read about logic circuits way long back in undergrad so my recall now may be completely wrong. I'm just making an attempt to answer... While circuits take *time*, the term **Latency** is defined in the [architectures-optimization-manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html) as *The number of clock cycles that are required for the execution core to complete the execution of all the µops that form an instruction.* (Again, you really seem more knowledgeable than me about circuits. I may be wrong.)

Comment: @Brut3Forc3: Updated my answer to include your queries.

Comment: @displayName that's right, but the premise of OPs question is "what if I make the frequency so high that an addition won't be complete in a cycle", which of course leads addition instructions getting a latency of at least 2 cycles in processor C (but not in A). Then he sets it so that the addition will be complete shortly into the second cycle, "wasting" the time between that and the next cycle. This relies on Tessellating being wrong - combinational circuits don't depend on clock speed, but on their inherent properties and driving voltage, so in all 3 processors that will take 10ns

Comment: @harold: The real issue is that two different concepts are being mixed. Time taken by a circuit is independent of clock speed of a processor. To really compare processors, one will need to fix at least 2 params out of 3 as mentioned in the last section of my answer.

Comment: @displayName we have them though (sort of), the target frequency is given, and so is the delay of a logic element that must be in there, so we can infer how many cycles we need for the addition instruction (unless it spends some extra cycles doing god knows what) and the frequency was given, that's two out of three

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert BUT I'd say ...

the regular assumption that processors with high clock cycles are faster FOR THE VAST MAJORITY OF OPERATIONS

For example, a more intelligent processor might perform an "overhead task" that takes X ns. The "overhead task" might make it faster for repetitive operations but might actually cause it to take longer for a one-off operation such as adding 2 numbers.

Now, if the same processor performed that same operation 1 million times, it should be massively faster than the slower less intelligent processor.

Hope my thinking helps. Your feedback on my thoughts welcome.

Comment: sorry but it answer is completely out of context to my question .

Answer (score 1):

Why would a faster processor take more cycles to do the same operation than a slower one?

Even more important: modern processors use [Instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining), thus executing multiple operations in one clock cycle.

Also, I don't understand what you mean by *'wasting 5ns'*, the frequency determines the clock speed, thus the time it takes to execute *1 clock*. Of course, cpu's can have to wait on I/O for example, but that holds for all cpu's.

Another important aspect of modern cpu's are the L1, L2 and L3 caches and the architecture of those caches in multicore systems. For example: if a register access takes 1 time unit, a L1 cache access will take around 2 while a normal memory access will take between 50 and 100 (and a harddisk access would take thousands..).

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 - Normally it does, but to make it more general for all possible types of cpu/mcu, I used time units instead. The ratio between those numbers is more important here.

Comment: so basically one operation is performed in one cycle. But here operations means just ADD i.e. adding two numbers or the bunch of operations such as fetch decode and execute combined in one instruction.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 - Depends on what you ADD, register-register, or register-memory, etc.. - With instruction pipelining, even multiple ADD's could be executed in a single cycle, or at least use some overlapping to get to more than one instruction/cycle on average.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually almost correct, except that on processor B taking 2 cycles means 14ns, so with 10ns being enough the next cycle starts 4ns after the result was already "stable" (though it is likely that you need some extra time if you chop it up, to latch the partial result). It's not that much of a contradiction, setting your frequency "too high" can require trade-offs like that. An other thing you might do it use more a different circuit or domino logic to get the actual latency of addition down to one cycle again. More likely, you wouldn't set addition at 2 cycles to begin with. It doesn't work out so well in this case, at least not for addition. You could do it, and yes, basically you will have to "round up" the time a circuit takes to an integer number of cycles. You can also see this in bitwise operations, which take less time than addition but nevertheless take a whole cycle. On machine C you could probably still fit bitwise operations in a single cycle, for some workloads it might even be worth splitting addition like that.

FWIW, Netburst (Pentium 4) had staggered adders, which computed the lower half in one "half-cycle" and the upper half in the next (and the flags in the third half cycle, in some sense giving the whole addition a latency of 1.5). It's not completely out of this world, though Netburst was over all, fairly mad - it had to do a lot of weird things to get the frequency up that high. But those half-cycles aren't very half (it wasn't, AFAIK, logic that advanced on every flank, it just used a clock multiplier), you could also see them as the real cycles that are just very fast, with most of the rest of the logic (except that crazy ALU) running at half speed.

Comment: cannot find the chat anymore bro. Kindly post a link

Answer (score 1):

Your broad point that 'a CPU will occasionally waste clock cycles' is valid. But overall in the real world, part of what makes a good CPU a good CPU is how it alleviates this problem.

Modern CPUs consist of a number of different components, none of whose operations will end up taking a constant time in practice. For example, an ADD instruction might 'burst' at 1 instruction per clock cycle if the data is immediately available to it... which in turn means something like 'if the CPU subcomponents required to fetch that data were immediately available prior to the instruction'. So depending on if e.g. another subcomponent had to wait for a cache fetch, the ADD may in practice take 2 or 3 cycles, say. A good CPU will attempt to re-order the incoming stream of instructions to maximise the availability of subcomponents at the right time.

So you could well have the situation where a particular series of instructions is 'suboptimal' on one processor compared to another. And the overall performance of a processor is certainly not just about raw clock speed: it is as much about the clever logic that goes around taking a stream of incoming instructions and working out which parts of which instructions to fire off to which subcomponents of the chip when.

But... I would posit that any modern chip contains such logic. Both a 2GHz and a 3GHz processor will regularly "waste" clock cycles because (to put it simply) a "fast" instruction executed on one subcomponent of the CPU has to wait for the result of the output from another "slower" subcomponent. But overall, you will still expect the 3GHz processor to "execute real code faster".

Comment: I have two very basic questions to which I'm still confused.           1.What does a ADD instruction mean, does it purely mean only and only ADD(with operands available at the registers) or does it mean getting the operands, decoding the instruction and then actually adding the numbers.    2. Based on the above context to what add actually means, how many cycles does add take, one or more than one.  Everyone has a different opinion on these two questions which confuses me so much.

Comment: So usually what we call "the ADD instruction" comprises all of the steps that are contained in a "single line of assembler" (and, to the processor, all of the steps that are implied by a particular sequence of bytes that the processor recognises as "an instruction" on some macro level). As to "how many cycles", the answer is... "it's complicated". The processor will typically have a number of subcomponents, each of which can potentially advance every clock cycle, and a given instruction will need some context-dependent number of these to have "advanced" to complete the instruction.

Comment: So overall, a particular instruction will take some average range of cycles. It's rarely possible to say "this instruction is guaranteed to take this many cycles". (At least, this is true on a modern, general-purpose CPU. On older architectures, or on a processor designed specifically as a "real-time" controller, the processor may well offer you a guarantee of so-many-cycles-per-instruction.)

Comment: But shouldn't be there a strict minimum time that addition takes, i.e. addition for instance will definitely take 20ns and no less than that no matter how fast the cpu is. Or it is possible to break every boundary just by overclocking the cpu !

Comment: Well, the laws of physics do ultimately set limits on things, yes. I'm not sure the issue boils down to a "strict minimum time to perform operation X" so much as a more general limit on how close together different paths of flowing electrons can be without interfering with one another.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the 10ns time to perform the addition does not include the pipeline overhead (clock skew and latch delay), then Processor B cannot complete an addition (with these overheads) in one 10ns clock cycle, but Processor A can and Processor C can still probably do it in two cycles.

Second, if the addition itself is pipelined (or other functional units are available), then a subsequent *non-dependent* operation can begin executing in the next cycle. (If the addition was width-pipelined/staggered (as mentioned in [harold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34597638/2467198)) then even dependent additions, logical operations and left shifts could be started after only one cycle. However, if the exercise is constraining addition timing, it presumably also prohibits other optimizations to simplify the exercise.) If dependent operations are not especially common, then the faster clock of Processor C will result in higher performance. (E.g., if a dependence stall occurred every fourth cycle, then, ignoring other effects, Processor C can complete four instructions every five 7ns cycles (35 ns; the first three instruction overlap in execution) compared to 40ns for Processor B (assuming the add timing included pipelining overhead).) (Note: Your assumption 3 is incorrect, two cycles for Processor C would be 14ns.)

Third, the extra time in a clock cycle can be used to support more complex operations (e.g., preshifting one operand by a small immediate value and even adding three numbers — a carry-save adder has relatively little delay), to steal work from other pipeline stages (potentially reducing the number of pipeline stages, which generally reduces branch misprediction penalties), or to reduce area or power by using simpler logic. In addition, the extra time might be used to support a larger (or more associative) cache with fixed latency in cycles, reducing miss rates. Such factors can compensate for the "waste" of 5ns in Processor A.

Even for scalar (single issue per cycle) pipelines clock speed is not the single determinant of performance. Design choices become even more complex when power, manufacturing cost (related to yield, adjusted according to sellable bins, and area), time-to-market (and its variability/predictability), workload diversity, and more advanced architectural and microarchitectural techniques are considered.

The incorrect assumption that clock frequency determines performance even has a name: the [Megahertz myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth).

Comment: Sir I request you to please reply on this being as simple as possible, I have two very basic questions to which I'm still confused. 1.What does a ADD instruction mean, does it purely mean only and only ADD(with operands available at the registers) or does it mean getting the operands, decoding the instruction and then actually adding the numbers. 2. Based on the above context to what add actually means, how many cycles does add take, one or more than one. Everyone has a different opinion on these two questions which confuses me so much.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 "enforced by the gate manufacturers" implies (to me) that it is referring to the addition operation (i.e., adding the two numbers together) not the ADD instruction because the operation is more primitive (more closely tied to manufacturing technology, though even addition latency is not fixed by manufacturing technology).  I assume this is in the context of pipelined processors, so the time required to fully process an ADD instruction is less useful since other instructions can begin processing while the ADD is still in the pipeline. Your confusion is understandable since

Comment: the exercise seems not to be expressed clearly. "operation" implies the addition itself (not the other aspects of instruction processing), but "that" links the operation to "an *instruction* to add two numbers". If the exercise was in the context of non-pipelined processors, I would be inclined (based on "that") to assume the 10ns applied to the entire instruction since instruction processing time is not overlapped in a non-pipelined processor.

Comment: (For non-pipelined designs, a faster clock might facilitate logic reuse — e.g., using a half-width adder — reducing size or more closely matching instruction processing times to integer clock cycles.) In the exercise, this would imply A wastes 5ns and C wastes 4ns (two 7ns cycles to process the ADD instruction). Sadly lack of clarity seems common for computer architecture exercises. In trying to simply the issues assumptions are made but often not explicitly declared.